# How to detect exact position of one click mouse , and use this position for other work

Tags: python, pygame, click

I use this code to get a separate position of each left click on `pygame`:

```
 for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            running=False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
```

I use `mouse_x` and `mouse_y` for drawing , but they are always change. So, how to get an exact position of each click on a screen in `pygame` and to use them to draw ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### 1. To get the position when the mouse is clicked

You can use [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to get the position at the exact frame when you *begin* to press the button like that:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * # import constants like MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button = 0: # detect only left clicks
            print(event.pos)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

### 2. To get the position each frame

In this case, you can use [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html) like that:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * # import constants like MOUSEBUTTONDOWN

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

#### If you want to get the mouse position only if the left button is pressed:

Place the line `print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())` in `if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:`:

```py
...

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: # if left button of the mouse pressed
        print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

...
```

Answer (score -2):

This code actually detects all kinds of mouse clicks, if you just want the left clicks you can add this to your if statement:

```
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
```

You are also not getting the coordinates the right way, you need to write it like this:

```
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

If you need to use all the clicks that are happening you need to store the x_mouse and y_mouse to a log which you can do like this:

```
# This outside the pygame loop
mouse_clicks = []

# This inside the pygame loop
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event.type==QUIT:
       running=False
   elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
       mouse_clicks.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
```

Now you have a list of tuples with all x,y coordinates for all clicks

Comment: you have an email ? , please help me more about this , due to a long code , so , i cannot post to here. Thank you

Comment: Then narrow down your question. The solution provided here does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: *You are also not getting the coordinates the right way*: that's simply not true at all. When a mouse click happens, the event object will contain the position in its `pos` attribute. If you use `pygame.mouse.get()` instead, you get the current mouse position, which may be different if you e.g. click while moving the mouse very fast.

Comment: @sloth, I did not know. When I tried to print the event.pos I got an error saying event has no attribute pos.

Comment: @eligolf the event object does not always have all possible attributes. You can look [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) to see when each attribute is avaible. As you can see, the `pos` attribute is only set when the `type` of the event object is `MOUSEMOTION`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` or `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`